# How to split 2 rows having 3 cols each into 3 rows having 2 cols each on mobile screen using BS4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, grid

I've 2 rows of 3 cols on desktop view like this:

```
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        1
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        2
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        3
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        1
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        2
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        3
      </div>
    </div>
```

and I want them to split automatically into 3 rows of 2 columns on mobile like this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    1
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    2
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    3
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    1
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    2
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    3
  </div>
</div>
```

Is there a predefined method in bs4 to do that or something only CSS I don't want to use js for this because there are too many rows and columns having different ids and class. Thanks!

Comment: use `col-6` instead of `col-xs-6`.

Comment: Then add each `col` div in a single `row` class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this instead,

You can use the `col` div item in a single `row` class.

`col-xs-*` have been dropped in Bootstrap 4 in favor of `col-*`.

Replace `col-xs-6` with `col-6` and it will work as expected.

**Desktop view**
[image]

**Mobile View**

[image]

More information about **[Bootstrap Grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/)**

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container mt-3 text-center">
  <div class="row w-100 mx-auto">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-6 border">1</div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-6 border">2</div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-6 border">3</div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-6 border">1</div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-6 border">2</div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-6 border">3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm">
        1
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm">
        2
      </div>
</div>

<div class="row">

      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm">
        1
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm">
        2
      </div>

</div>

<div class="row">

      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm">
        1
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm">
        2
      </div>

</div>
```